# How can I use capybara to test view functionality based on USER_AGENTs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I have some functionality in a rails 3.2 app that needs to be driven by the user's USER_AGENT. Basically, for certain older browsers I need to have the pages render differently.

How can I test that my views respond correctly using using capybara / cucumber?

I saw this post but it doesn't look like it works with the lastest capybara -- it basically hacks the way capybara stubs environmental parameters:

http://blog.sparqcode.com/2011/03/07/custom-user-agent-strings-with-cucumber-and-capybara/

What I'd like is a cucumber step definition that looks something like this:

```
When /^I visit the page with an unsupported browser$/ do
  user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.0.2) Gecko/2008092313 Ubuntu/9.25 (jaunty) Firefox/3.8"
  # do something here that mimics the user arriving on the page with this USER_AGENT
end
```

Comment: In the end, I resolved this issue by using capybara-webkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Firefox to run your tests, you can create a custom driver with whatever USER_AGENT you like.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5671840/74152).

Once you've created a custom driver, you can use it when running a scenario simply by tagging the scenario with the drivers name, e.g if you do `Capybara.register_driver :old_browser`, you can tag the scenario as `@old_browser`, and Capybara will automatically switch drivers.  If you don't like that, you can switch drivers at any time you like: `Capybara.current_driver = :old_browser`.

Comment: Thanks! This works and does generally exactly what I need! However, it literally launches a browser when that test runs and closes it after. None of my other cucumber tests actually launch a browser. Do you know how I can suppress this?

Comment: Glad it works, I wasn't sure from your question if you were already using a browser driver, obviously you weren't!  Not much you can do about it unless you find some other way to change the user agent - as this method relies on using Firefox profiles, hence the firefox browser launching!

Comment: I had someone on irc #capyabara recommend using capybara-webkit. See https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/blob/master/spec/driver_spec.rb